# Cannot drag and drop nor hover, on the whole system, when Razer mouse is plugged in

Tags: macos, mouse, bug, driver, plist

I have only been able to identify that it happens when that mouse is plugged in because, with any other mouse, it doesn't happen. Sporadically it fixes itself but I have not been able to figure out what has changed to cause the trick to occur. I have already reported the bug [here](https://github.com/1kc/razer-macos/issues/752) but have had no response. Would it be possible to change any of the .plist files to fix this problem? I have already tried the common solutions but none seem to work. However, any suggestions are welcome.

System details :

- macOS Ventura Version 13.3.1 (a) (22E772610a)
- MacBook Pro 2019 (but it also happened with an M1 2020)
- Razer BlackWidow V3 Pro (wired)
- Razer Basilisk Ultimate (wired or dongle) (but the latter is the one causing problems)

Comment: Including some of the detail from your external link might be helpful, but first thing I'd suggest would be to update your OS, just in case a later version has alredy fixed it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response and sorry for omitting useful information. I will edit it. But as you will see, I am already on the latest version.

Comment: If the problem only manifests with the dongle, it’s likely a hardware issue with the wireless connection between the mouse and dongle.  If it works when wired, you’ve confirmed this.  It’s not a macOS issue to fix.

Comment: You said you tried the usual? eg. restart Mac, repair mouse, toggle Bluetooth. If you can use the mouse but not hover or drag a drop, it is likely a problem in macOS, not a hardware issue. Did you try the things listed here: https://www.makeuseof.com/mouse-not-working-mac-fix/?

Comment: Thanks, @Allan, and sorry for the misunderstanding but the issue is present both ways.

Comment: Also thanks, @JustMakeStuff, there were some solutions I had not tried yet; but unfortunately, none of them worked.

Comment: Strange… Better contact Razer, could be defective?